# Linux kernel API changes/additions

Tags: linux, api, linux-kernel

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I'm trying to find a webpage or docs or XYZ that will allow me to see all the API changes/additions/removals between two kernel versions.

I found http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges , but I'm not sure it lists everything as I know that Netlink API changed somewhere between 3.5 and 3.6 but it doesn't appear on that page.

Regards

Comment: The question asks meta information about Linux, that's not programming related.

Comment: Probably http://unix.stackexchange.com/ . Its description is "Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.."

Comment: @JohannesWeiß API changes definitely are programming related.

Comment: @CL. thanks for enlightening me, I misunderstood the question. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See kernel API/ABI tracker here: http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/linux/

The analysis was done by the [*abi-compliance-checker*](https://github.com/lvc/abi-compliance-checker) and [*abi-dumper*](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper) tools.

Analysis reports show added/removed symbols, detailed changes in parameters and data types in the *vmlinux* binary and basic modules. I maintain this page, so feel free to ask me to check any particular kernel versions.

[image]

Comment: I think this is exacly what I need. For my project (https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon) I'll need all the changes between 2.6.33 and current kernel, for both x86 and x64. I understand that this is a lot of work, and that maybe you don't have enough time to do it, so I can help you. :)

Comment: @alexandernst - I'm currently have a time to create and share such report. You can help me by sharing anywhere necessary input files for analysis: vmlinux compiled with minimal debug-info of both versions and both architectures.

Comment: Ok, I'll start with 3.10. Where can I send you links to the files? Email maybe?

Comment: @alexandernst - email in my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/241776/aponomarenko

Comment: Email isn't public :p. Mine is alexandernst@gmail.com

Comment: @alexandernst - I've built necessary kernel versions on x86 and I'll publish reports tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concentrated effort to collect the details of all API changes.

The [LinuxChanges page](http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges) lists the following change:

> packet: nlmon: virtual netlink monitoring device for packet sockets ([commit](http://git.kernel.org/linus/e4fc408e0e99fd2e009c8b3702d9637f5554fd5c))

[LWN.net](http://lwn.net) has overviews for all import changes in a merge window:
[3.6 merge window part 1](http://lwn.net/Articles/507852/)
[3.6 merge window part 2](http://lwn.net/Articles/508790/)
[The conclusion of the 3.6 merge window](http://lwn.net/Articles/509433/)

For 3.6, it has:

> - The NLMSG_NEW() and NLMSG_PUT() macros have been removed from the netlink interface.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the entire API change that was done between 3.5 and 3.6. From what I get from my tests, at least one more change happened: in ```netlink_kernel_create```. I'll ask in ##kernel too. Thanks for the help :)